# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Smarty::Smarty()

Tags: php, smarty

```
<?php 
require_once  SMARTY_DIR . 'Smarty.class.php';
 class Application extends Smarty 
 {
   public function __construct()
   {
  parent::Smarty();
  $this->template_dir = TEMPLATE_DIR;
  $this->compile_dir = COMPILE_DIR;
  $this->config_dir = CONFIG_DIR;
   }
}
?>
```

i m getting error as Fatal error: Call to undefined method Smarty::Smarty()
I have used a Smarty software in php project folder 
but i m getting error 
i m using this Smarty software first time in php 
i m not getting the clue in this code

Answer (score 1):

To call the parent constructor you have to use

```
  parent::__construct();
```

instead of `parent::Smarty();`

Comment: Worth noting: `parent::Smarty();` was probably valid at one point. Constructors in PHP used to the name of the class (therefore `Smarty`s constructor was actually named `Smarty()`. The library is old enough that I'd be willing to believe it did that at one point. I just checked github, it looks like neither current version or it's backwards-compatibility wrapper support the PHP 4 style syntax.

Comment: @ArSen now new errro Warning: Smarty error: unable to read resource: "site.conf" in C:\xampp\htdocs\tshirtshop\libs\smarty\Smarty.class.php on line 1100

Comment: @Technicalstudieslogic then you are probably missing some configuraiton file from smarty, as the error says. see https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/config.files.tpl